# What would you suggest for filtering feed info

Tags: info-visualisation, sorting, filter

we provide users the flexibility to filter and sort the info they want to see in feeds around the platform.

Today we use drop down but all the click are annoying  we want a better ux
We came up with this option. What do you think?

[image]

Comment: How will it look when `Specific member` is chosen? also, are keyboard users important to you? because it doesn't look keyboard friendly

Comment: are you designing for a mobile app?

Comment: The website is responsive. I was thinking if someone choose specific member a drop down list with members will be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Your option are radio buttons but in a design that **makes them look like [steppers](https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html)**, which is a bit confusing:

[image]

I would suggest using the radio buttons you are using, but in a list way, one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks like a slider with fixed steps or a wizard stepper like Alvaro said.

[image]

The lines between radio buttons are the main cause of confusion. If you remove the lines, the buttons will look like the radio buttons.